# How to pad headerbox in baposter

Tags: baposter

Is there a way to pad a headerbox in baposter so that the margin of the text inside the box frame can be customized?

Comment: Maybe a MWE (and a drawing of what you want to achieve) helps?!

Comment: Guess: I would try to use the tikz options such as inner sep= or inner xsep= and so on, if this is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing of the `posterbox` environment (which has replaced the  `\headerbox` macro) using the `boxpadding` key, and adjust the header height also using the `boxheaderheight` key.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape]{baposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
columns=3,
textborder=none,
headerColorOne={red!50},
bgColorOne={blue!20},
bgColorTwo={blue!40}
  }
  {
    Eye Catcher, empty if option eyecatcher=no
  }
  {
    Poster Title
} {
    Poster Authors
  }
  {%logo
    \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}
}
\begin{posterbox}[%
    name=box1,
    column=0,
    span=1,
    row=0,
    boxpadding=1em
]
{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\end{itemize}
\end{posterbox}
\begin{posterbox}[%
    name=box2,
    column=1,
    span=1,
    row=0,
    boxpadding=2em,
    boxheaderheight=4em
]
{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\end{itemize}
\end{posterbox}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1: Did you find that in the manual?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Channeling David Carlisle, why read the manual when you can just read the code. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn you learn well:-)